# How to extend will_paginate for a rails gem with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, will-paginate

need some help.
I have been updating a gem for a rails forum software. It would usually require ActiveRecord but I have converted a majority of the gem to Mongoid.

Now here is where I need some help, I am attempting to use will_paginate's per_page method.

Here is the code provided.

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
module WillPaginate
ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
  module ActiveRecord
    module RelationMethods
      alias_method :per, :per_page
      alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Now the problem is I am using Mongoid, and I am unsure exactly how I would convert this to mongoid.
If someone could help me I would appreciate that.

Resources:

Mongoid-
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid

Will_paginate-
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: may be this will be useful for you https://github.com/lucasas/will_paginate_mongoid

Comment: Yeah I looked at that before, but what I need help with is finding the actual way in the method above on how I would add the alias_methods to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mongoid, you have to user will_paginate_mongoid. If that doesn't work, you can look at this cuestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823366/will-paginate-with-mongoid-total-entries-issue). Anyway, just adding will_paginate_mongoid gem to my Gemfile worked for me.